# Duplicate Data Stop in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, duplicate-data

I have a table below :

```
+-----+-------+------+------------+
| ID  | RefID | Type | EventTime  |
+-----+-------+------+------------+
| 101 |   228 |    1 | 1437195633 |
| 102 |   228 |    5 | 1437195633 |
| 103 |   228 |    1 | 1437195633 |
| 104 |   228 |    1 | 1437195442 |
| 105 |   228 |    1 | 1437195442 |
| 106 |   228 |    5 | 1437195442 |
| 107 |   228 |    1 | 1437165634 |
| 108 |   228 |    5 | 1437165442 |
| 109 |   228 |    1 | 1437165634 |
| 110 |   228 |    5 | 1437165442 |
+-----+-------+------+------------+
```

In that I want to stop inserting `duplicate` data based on the columns `RefID,Type,EventTime` only when value of `Type = 1`.

In the above table `ID` pair is duplicate `(101,103), (104,105), (107,109)`.

If now I will insert another data say :

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES('',228,1,1437165634);
```

Then it should not `insert`. I am checking while inserting into that table but that is not working as I have checked at the same time `2 insert` query is happening, I need to stop it using `UNIQUE key` constraints.

Comment: can you add your code as well. And are you using any framework or just native php

Comment: So add the unique composite key to the 3 columns you mentioned, where's the problem exactly?

Comment: Do you want add unique index and remove duplicates, right?

Comment: I want to add unique key based on the value of "Type" columns when it is 1 then only that constraints should work and I am using Yii framework for development. I have placed check twice for duplicate data not to insert into table at Model level while saving and before saving but the data is coming so frequently that it is not allowing the duplicate data to insert. Difference between two record time may be 100 ms or 500 ms

Answer (score 0):

You need change DB architecture. Add table with unique index by RefId, here you will write record with Type "1". In your Yii model in method beforesave check your Type if is 1 to write in added table otherwise write to old table. And you need change beforefind method

And I'm sorry for my english

Comment: I have resolved it by using trigger thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
public function unique($attribute, $params)
{
    if(!empty($model_name)){
            $this->addError('RefID', 'RefID already exists! Please choose a different one');
            return true;}
}
```

as a custom function in before save. and call it for the fields you want in the rule. I'm showing you the template for a single field `refID`

Comment: I have resolved it by using trigger and handled error in Model save(). I have used signal sqlstate in trigger which have resolved my problem

Comment: cool but Model save() or u meant function save()? Cause that function save() is usually called in the controller.. and you shouldn't use PDO or SQL statements in controllers,u should work it out within models. Controller should be slick and lesser in size

Comment: I have added code for it also you can see there. Thank you for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by using trigger as below :

**DB Trigger**

```
delimiter $$

drop trigger if exists stop_duplicate $$
create trigger stop_duplicate before insert on table
for each row
begin
  set @found := false;
  if new.Type = 1 then
SELECT 
        TRUE
    INTO @found FROM
        table
    WHERE
        RefID = new.RefID AND EventTime= new.EventTime AND Type= new.Type;

      if @found then
        signal sqlstate '23000' set message_text = 'CUSTOM_MSG_DUPLICATE';
        end if;
end if;
end   $$
delimiter ;
```

**Yii Model Code**

```
public function save($runValidation = true, $attributes = null) {
    Yii::log(__METHOD__.":: Start ", 'info');
    try {
        return parent::save();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $errorInfo = $e instanceof PDOException ? $e->errorInfo : null;
        $message = $e->getMessage();
        Yii::log(__METHOD__ . ": errorcode :{$e->getCode()}, errormessage:{$message} ", 'info');
        // Added for handling duplicate entry issue for index
        if ((int) $e->getCode() === 23000 && strpos($message, 'CUSTOM_MSG_DUPLICATE') !== false) {
            return false;
        }
        throw new CDbException(Yii::t('yii', 'CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: {error}', array('{error}' => $message)), (int) $e->getCode(), $errorInfo);
    }
}
```