# mysql constraint or trigger

Tags: mysql, sql

How to make sure that a couple of rows (A,B) values can be duplicated but can have only one corresponding value in row C in the same table ?

Suppose i am inserting these rows in this order this the output i want to have.

**EDIT:** 
what i want is that when A,B,C is inserted for the first time value in C will be the unique possible value for the couple (A,B)

this means, if i, insert (0,0) with C = 1 when there is no other (0,0) couples in (A,B) then the row is accepted.But if i add (0,0) for the second(third ..) time; then C has to be equal to 1.

example :

```
A | B | C | D | F  ...
_________________
0 | 0 |1
0 | 0 |1
0 | 0 |2 --> not allowed
1 | 0 |3 --> allowed
1 | 0 |2 --> not allowed
1 | 0 |3 --> allowed
```

Comment: more examples please. and what about (allowed/not) 0 | 0 |1 ?

Comment: Your rules on what is allowed and not allowed are not clear.

Comment: I updated the question. Check it please!

Comment: Check the [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32090658/duplicate-data-stop-in-mysql) solved using Trigger search the text on the page "DB Trigger"

Comment: i believe thet last 1 | 0 |3 should be allowed?

Comment: oups Yes! 1 | 0 | 3 should be allowed. Fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

try this trigger

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER wtf_dupes BEFORE INSERT ON your_table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET @ok := TRUE;

    SELECT FALSE INTO @ok FROM your_table
    WHERE 
            A = new.A 
        AND B = new.B 
        AND C <> new.C
    LIMIT 1 
    ;

    IF NOT @ok THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '23000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'YourMessageAboutDupeError';
    END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

about how to trap signals you should do your own investigation:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html#signal-effects

Answer (score 0):

Although there is a way to [create a trigger that checks another table or view](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html)
for already existing value combinations, there is a question on [canceling insert from within a trigger in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538786/how-to-abort-insert-operation-in-mysql-trigger) and the accepted answer says that there is no such feature. So I think you have to implement this in application logic or move the insert to a procedure.